How to get constant symbol value in ethers v6
If I have this contract definition (for example):
library TickMath {
    /// @dev The minimum tick that may be passed to #getSqrtRatioAtTick computed from log base 1.0001 of 2**-128
    int24 internal constant MIN_TICK = -887272;
    /// @dev The maximum tick that may be passed to #getSqrtRatioAtTick computed from log base 1.0001 of 2**128
    int24 internal constant MAX_TICK = -MIN_TICK;

....

and I have the ABI of it, how do I get the value of MIN_TICK using ethers v6 in, say , hardhat test script? I want to get the value which is -887272 , using javascript. Since it is not a function (nor a state variable), and the contract isn't deployed (it can't be deployed because it is a library), the interface object returned by getContractFactory() method doesn't contain the value. So where is the value stored and how do you get it programmatically?

You can compile the TickMath library using Hardhat, it generates an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), which is a structured representation of the code.
This AST is part of the build-info files in Hardhat’s artifacts/build-info directory. The AST contains metadata about variables, functions, and other elements in the contract, including constant values.
Once you have the AST, you need to traverse it to locate the constant variable declarations:

MIN_TICK: This is stored as an int24 with a negative value (as defined in the AST under UnaryOperation).

MAX_TICK: This is derived from MIN_TICK and is stored as -MIN_TICK (indicating that it's the positive counterpart of MIN_TICK).


Here's the script for the same:
const hre = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

async function main() {
    // Path to the compiled contracts output
    const compiledOutputPath = path.join(__dirname, "../artifacts/build-info");

    // Read the build info files
    const files = fs.readdirSync(compiledOutputPath);
    const buildInfoFile = path.join(compiledOutputPath, files[0]);

    const buildInfo = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(buildInfoFile, "utf8"));

    // Traverse through the output sources to find the AST
    const contracts = buildInfo.output.sources['contracts/TickMath.sol'];

    let minTickValue;
    let maxTickValue;

    if (contracts && contracts.ast) {
        const ast = contracts.ast;

        // Find MIN_TICK in the AST
        ast.nodes.forEach((node) => {
            if (node.nodeType === "ContractDefinition" && node.name === "TickMath") {
                node.nodes.forEach((subNode) => {
                    // Handle MIN_TICK value
                    if (subNode.nodeType === "VariableDeclaration" && subNode.name === "MIN_TICK") {
                        const valueNode = subNode.value;
                        if (valueNode.nodeType === "UnaryOperation" && valueNode.operator === '-') {
                            // MIN_TICK is negative
                            const literalValue = valueNode.subExpression.value;
                            minTickValue = `-${literalValue}`;
                        } else if (valueNode.nodeType === "Literal") {
                            // MIN_TICK is positive
                            minTickValue = valueNode.value;
                        }
                    }

                    // Handle MAX_TICK value (derived from MIN_TICK)
                    if (subNode.nodeType === "VariableDeclaration" && subNode.name === "MAX_TICK") {
                        const valueNode = subNode.value;
                        if (valueNode.nodeType === "UnaryOperation" && valueNode.operator === '-') {
                            // MAX_TICK is defined as -MIN_TICK
                            const referencedNode = valueNode.subExpression;
                            if (referencedNode.nodeType === 'Identifier' && referencedNode.name === 'MIN_TICK') {
                                maxTickValue = -minTickValue;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (valueNode.nodeType === 'Identifier' && valueNode.name === 'MIN_TICK') {
                            // MAX_TICK is defined as MIN_TICK
                            maxTickValue = minTickValue;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Output the results
        if (minTickValue !== undefined) {
            console.log(`MIN_TICK found with value: ${minTickValue}`);
        } else {
            console.log("MIN_TICK not found.");
        }

        if (maxTickValue !== undefined) {
            console.log(`MAX_TICK found with value: ${maxTickValue}`);
        } else {
            console.log("MAX_TICK not found.");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No AST found for the contract.");
    }
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

You can also refer to this repository that I've created for this use-case.

great stuff! thank you very much! If such amount of extra code is needed, then I suppose ethers.js doesn't have  (neither hardhat) a built-in function to fetch constant value? right?

You’re welcome. Yes, there’s no built-in function to fetch a constant value, mainly because constants are not part of the ABI, as constants are compile-time values, and the ABI is used for runtime interactions with contracts. In other words, constants do not require getters and are immutable, they are directly embedded in the bytecode, which is why the ABI doesn’t expose them for interaction.
